# Programmatically-added page control disappears when setting view controllers after setup

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

## Problem

When tapping the skip button on page `i` (which calls `setViewControllers(_:animated:)` and transitions the user to the last page in the page view controller), and then swiping back to page `i` again, the page control disappears.

## Wanted result

I want to *programmatically* add and show a custom page control on the bottom of each view controller in a page view controller when said page view controller contains different types of view controllers.

## Efforts so far to resolve the issue

- Adding the page control to the base view controller *each time it appears*.
- Calling `loadView()` on the view controller that contains the missing page control.

## Code

I have a `WalkthroughRootViewController` that contains a `UIPageViewController`. The type of the view controllers in the page view controller are two subclasses of type `WalkthroughBaseViewController`, the first `n-1` of one type, and the last of the other. I have not included code of the last type, as that's working as far as I can see.

I have this code in `WalkthroughBaseViewController`:

```
lazy var pageControl: UIPageControl = {
    let pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: .zero)
    pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
    pageControl.sizeToFit()
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = Colors.brown
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = Colors.silver
    pageControl.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    pageControl.isEnabled = false
    return pageControl
}()
```

The page control is added to the view in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
view.addSubview(pageControl)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    pageControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
    pageControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
])
```

If the user is on any of the first `n-1` view controllers, there is a skip button the user can tap to skip forward to the last view controller. The code for this is

```
func skipWalkthrough() {
    guard let viewController = walkthroughPageViewControllerDataSource.viewController(at: lastIndex, storyboard: storyboard!) else { return }
    walkthroughPageViewController.setViewControllers([viewController], direction: .forward, animated: true)
}
```

## Reference

I have highlighted the code I believe is important, but here are all files related to the walkthrough of the application.

### `WalkthroughRootViewController`

```
import UIKit

class WalkthroughRootViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Regular Properties
    var walkthroughPageViewController: UIPageViewController!
    var walkthroughImages = [
        Images.w1,
        Images.w2
    ]
    var walkthroughStrings: [String] = [
        .localized(.walkthroughTitle1),
        .localized(.walkthroughZipCodeTitle)
    ]

    // MARK: Lazy Properties
    lazy var walkthroughPageViewControllerDataSource: WalkthroughPageViewControllerDataSource = {
        var dataSource = WalkthroughPageViewControllerDataSource()
        dataSource.walkthroughRootViewController = self
        return dataSource
    }()

    // MARK: Computed Properties
    var lastIndex: Int {
        return walkthroughImages.count - 1
    }
    var temporaryUserInput: String?
    var temporarySwitchPosition = false

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}

// MARK: View Controller Life Cycle

extension WalkthroughRootViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Stop gray shadow from appearing under transition.
        navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .white

        configurePageViewController()
    }
}

// MARK: Helper Methods

extension WalkthroughRootViewController {
    func configurePageViewController() {
        walkthroughPageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        walkthroughPageViewController.dataSource = walkthroughPageViewControllerDataSource
        walkthroughPageViewController.delegate = walkthroughPageViewControllerDataSource

        let startingViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Strings.ViewControllerIdentifiers.walkthroughImage) as! WalkthroughImageViewController
        let startIndex = 0
        startingViewController.delegate = self
        startingViewController.pageIndex = startIndex
        startingViewController.text = walkthroughStrings[startIndex]
        startingViewController.image = walkthroughImages[startIndex]
        startingViewController.numberOfPages = walkthroughImages.count

        walkthroughPageViewController.setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true)
        walkthroughPageViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        add(walkthroughPageViewController)
    }
}

extension WalkthroughRootViewController: WalkthroughDelegate {
    func skipWalkthrough() {
        guard let viewController = walkthroughPageViewControllerDataSource.viewController(at: lastIndex, storyboard: storyboard!) else { return }
        walkthroughPageViewController.setViewControllers([viewController], direction: .forward, animated: true)
    }
}

extension WalkthroughRootViewController: WalkthrouZipCodeViewControllerDelegate {
    func walkththroughZipCodeViewController(_ viewController: WalkthroughZipCodeViewController, userEnteredText enteredText: String) {
        temporaryUserInput = enteredText
    }

    func walkthroughZipCodeViewController(_ viewController: WalkthroughZipCodeViewController, userChangedSwitchPosition position: Bool) {
        temporarySwitchPosition = position
    }
}
```

## `WalkthroughBaseViewController`

```
import UIKit

protocol WalkthroughDelegate: class {
    func skipWalkthrough()
}

class WalkthroughBaseViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: Regular Properties
    var pageIndex = 0
    var text = ""
    var delegate: WalkthroughDelegate?
    var numberOfPages = 0

    // Lazy Properties
    lazy var pageControl: UIPageControl = {
        let pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: .zero)
        pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
        pageControl.sizeToFit()
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = Colors.brown
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = Colors.silver
        pageControl.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        pageControl.isEnabled = false
        return pageControl
    }()
}

// MARK: View Controller Life Cycle

extension WalkthroughBaseViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = Colors.silver

        view.addSubview(pageControl)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pageControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            pageControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])

        view.accessibilityIdentifier = Strings.AccessibilityIdentifiers.walkthrough
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        pageControl.currentPage = pageIndex
    }
}
```

## `WalkthroughImageViewController`

```
import UIKit

class WalkthroughImageViewController: WalkthroughBaseViewController {
    // MARK: @IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            titleLabel.textColor = Colors.silver
            titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var skipWalkthroughButton: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            skipWalkthroughButton.setTitleColor(Colors.silver, for: .normal)
            skipWalkthroughButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredBoldFont(for: .body)
            skipWalkthroughButton.setTitle(.localized(.skip), for: .normal)
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! {
        didSet {
            imageView.layer.shadowColor = Colors.brown.cgColor
            imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
            imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
            imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
            imageView.clipsToBounds = false
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        }
    }

    // MARK: Regular Properties
    var image: UIImage?

    // MARK: View Controller Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.image = image
        titleLabel.text = text
    }
}

// MARK: @IBActions

extension WalkthroughImageViewController {
    @IBAction func skipWalkthrough(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.skipWalkthrough()
    }
}
```

## `WalkthroughPageViewControllerDataSource`

```
import UIKit

class WalkthroughPageViewControllerDataSource: NSObject {
    // MARK: Regular Properties
    var walkthroughRootViewController: WalkthroughRootViewController!
}

extension WalkthroughPageViewControllerDataSource: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = indexOfViewController(viewController as! WalkthroughBaseViewController)

        if index == NSNotFound || index == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        index -= 1

        return self.viewController(at: index, storyboard: walkthroughRootViewController.storyboard!)

    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = indexOfViewController(viewController as! WalkthroughBaseViewController)

        if index == NSNotFound {
            return nil
        }

        index += 1

        if index == walkthroughRootViewController.walkthroughImages.count {
            return nil
        }

        return self.viewController(at: index, storyboard: walkthroughRootViewController.storyboard!)
    }
}

extension WalkthroughPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func viewController(at index: Int, storyboard: UIStoryboard) -> WalkthroughBaseViewController? {
        if walkthroughRootViewController.walkthroughImages.count == 0 || index >= walkthroughRootViewController.walkthroughImages.count {
            return nil
        }

        var viewController: WalkthroughBaseViewController?

        if index == walkthroughRootViewController.lastIndex {
            viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Strings.ViewControllerIdentifiers.walkthroughZipCode) as? WalkthroughZipCodeViewController
            if let viewController = viewController as? WalkthroughZipCodeViewController {
                viewController.pageIndex = index
                viewController.walkthroughZipCodeDelegate = walkthroughRootViewController
                viewController.temporaryUserInput = walkthroughRootViewController.temporaryUserInput
                viewController.temporarySwitchPosition = walkthroughRootViewController.temporarySwitchPosition
                viewController.numberOfPages = walkthroughRootViewController.walkthroughImages.count
                viewController.image = walkthroughRootViewController.walkthroughImages[index]
            }
        } else {
            viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Strings.ViewControllerIdentifiers.walkthroughImage) as? WalkthroughImageViewController
            if let viewController = viewController as? WalkthroughImageViewController {
                viewController.delegate = walkthroughRootViewController
                viewController.pageIndex = index
                viewController.image = walkthroughRootViewController.walkthroughImages[index]
                viewController.text = walkthroughRootViewController.walkthroughStrings[index]
            }
        }

        return viewController
    }

    func indexOfViewController(_ viewController: WalkthroughBaseViewController) -> Int {
        return viewController.pageIndex
    }
}

extension WalkthroughPageViewControllerDataSource: UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
}
```

Comment: It's a bit off-topic, but try not to use `extension`s to override methods - it can cause you trouble - see https://medium.com/@stanislavsmida/dont-use-extensions-primary-for-structuring-your-code-7b3af9baae17

Comment: and why do you put `UIPageControl` in each child VC? why don't you create a single one that you would put in the `WalkthroughRootViewController` and update it when you navigate the pages?

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much, @MilanNosáľ! And thanks for the tip about `extension`s and overriden methods. Feel free to post that as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a single `UIPageControl` that you put in the WalkthroughRootViewController and update it when you navigate the pages - don't create a page control for each child.

Try not to use `extension`s to override methods - it can cause you trouble - see [this blog entry](https://medium.com/@stanislavsmida/dont-use-extensions-primary-for-structuring-your-code-7b3af9baae17).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but the fix was: "and why do you put UIPageControl in each child VC? why don't you create a single one that you would put in the WalkthroughRootViewController and update it when you navigate the pages?"

Comment: sorry, I was just playing CS:GO and was doing it in rush :D